# Scandit for Xamarin on Android - binding the .jar file

Tags: android, jar, xamarin

Scandit 4.2.1 for Xamarin/Android has a bug where certain phones have trouble scanning because the image is blurry. Scandit 4.3 seems to fix this issue. So I'm trying use the Scandit jar file in my Xamarin project. I'm using scanditsdk-community-android_4.3.0.zip found here: https://ssl.scandit.com/account/sdk. The zip file contains a ScanditSDK folder with a folder structure like this:

```
ScanditSDK/libs/armeabi/libscanditsdk-android-4.3.0.so

ScanditSDK/libs/armeabi-v7a/libscanditsdk-android-4.3.0.so

ScanditSDK/libs/x86/libscanditsdk-android-4.3.0.so

ScanditSDK/libs/scanditsdk-barcodepicker-android-4.3.0.jar
```

So I'm trying to create a bindings library from this. My folder structure looks like this in the bindings library project:

```
/Jars/scanditsdk-barcodepicker-android-4.3.0.jar

libs/armeabi/libscanditsdk-android-4.3.0.so

libs/armeabi-v7a/libscanditsdk-android-4.3.0.so

libs/x86/libscanditsdk-android-4.3.0.so
```

For all of the .so files, I have `Build Action: EmbeddedNativeLibrary` and `Copy to Output: Copy always`. For the .jar file I have `Build Action: EmbeddedJar` and `Copy to Output: Do not copy`.

I'm not really sure what I'm doing here to be honest. I'm just trying to follow instructions that I've found. When I try to build the project I get this error: `Error  21  The type or namespace name 'Type' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Scandit.Base.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`.

What do I need to do to get this to build?

Answer (score 1):

Good thing for you is there is already a component for this. =)

http://components.xamarin.com/view/scandit

Comment: `Scandit 4.2.1 for Xamarin/Android has a bug where certain phones have trouble scanning because the image is blurry.` Read carefully before answering.